# NDVI from rescaled Landsat 8 L2 product is out of range

Tags: qgis, python, ndvi, landsat, sentinel-2

I need to use Landsat 8/9, [level 2 products](https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-collection-2-level-2-science-products), to compute NDVI. I know that I need to scale band 4 and 5 before compute the index. [Here](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-use-scale-factor-landsat-level-2-science-products) there are the official scaling factors.

So, as example, I apply the scaling factor on band 4 from *LC09_L2SP_189032_20220714_20220719_02_T1*:

> 0.0000275 * B4 - 0.2

Same thing on band 5, but when I compute the NDVI the maximum and minimum are out of the range because they are equal to, respectively, 531.67 - -0.829.42. I'm using QGIS 3.22.9.

If I apply a canonical colormap for NDVI I can see normal values on mainland and values outside the validity range (black pixels correspond to values lower than -1 and blue pixels correnspond to values greather than 1) on the sea.

[image]

For another check I tried to compute NDVI on Sentinel 2 product *S2A_MSIL2A_20220721T095041_N0400_R079_T33TVE_20220721T142101.SAFE*. With this data I've no problems.

Is there another thing to do on Landsat 8 data after scaling?

**TEST WITH PYTHON**:

```
import rioxarray
from pathlib import Path

b4 = Path('/home/max/Downloads/LC09_L2SP_189032_20220714_20220719_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF')
b5 = Path('/home/max/Downloads/LC09_L2SP_189032_20220714_20220719_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF')


red = 0.0000275 * rioxarray.open_rasterio(filename=b4, masked=True) - 0.2
nir = 0.0000275 * rioxarray.open_rasterio(filename=b5, masked=True) - 0.2

ndvi = (nir - red) / (nir + red)


<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 7881, x: 7761)>
array([[[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        ...,
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 3.624e+05 3.624e+05 ... 5.952e+05 5.952e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.582e+06 4.582e+06 ... 4.346e+06 4.346e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
```

- NDVI min: -1163.61
- NDVI max: 1030.98

Comment: Quotient greater than one (or less than negative one) means that the numerator is greater than the denominator in absolute values, which does not make sense in the NDVI formula since pixels cannot have negative reflectance. I would start by checking if you have original pixel values less than 7273 in both bands, before scaling or calculating the index.

Comment: I've pixel values greather than 7273 for both bands. This bands comes directly from earthexplorer.usgs.gov Landsat Collection 2 Level 2.

Comment: If all pixels have values greater than 7273, apply the scale and check for pixels with reflectance less than zero. If you have pixels greater than 7273 but less than zero after scaling, the problem is with the algebra of the scaling. If don't have pixels less than zero the problem is in the algebra of the index, because the formula can't result greater than one or less than negative one.

Comment: You have a wrong formula in some place; possibly in NDVI calculation because scaling is correct. It is impossible that normalized differences of B5, B4 bands produce values out of range -1, 1; inclusively with ND values instead reflectances . By the way, LC09_L2SP_189032_20220714_02_T1 is not the correct LANDSAT_PRODUCT_ID.

Comment: @xunilk It's right, I've used the ID from Microsoft Planetary Computer. Now I've correct the mistake.
@GabrielDeLuca I use QGIS Raster Calculator for compute NDVI: `(B5 - B4) / (B5 + B4)`

Comment: I've the same problem with Python